# how to define media query with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, responsive

I have some buttons, and onclik scrolls to content and this code works good :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("button#defaultOpen").click(function() {
       jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery("#defaultOpen").offset().top+267
        }, 1000);
    });

     jQuery("button#spezialkurs").click(function() {
       jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery("#spezialkurs").offset().top+267
        }, 1000);
    });

    jQuery("button#opengym").click(function() {
       jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery("#opengym").offset().top+125
        }, 1000);
    });

    jQuery("button#challenge").click(function() {
       jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:jQuery("#challenge").offset().top+125
        }, 1000);
    });

    jQuery("button#vielseitige").click(function() {
      jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery("#vielseitige").offset().top-10
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

the problem is that I want to add media query that this code will run only above 768 ! or some more is wrong here ?

Thank you,

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to put the Media query in CSS directly? Also you should really research how to DRY up code. You can make all of those handlers in to one single one.

Comment: One of the benifits of media queries is that you have conditional CSS rules **without** using any scripts to make them happen.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes it could be great if you can dry up the code! Well I have no idea how can I add this code to CSS?

Comment: CSS -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, well what will be the CSS code that onclick to scroll to the content ? As you see I have fixed scrollings as top+125 or top top+267

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
if (screen.width > 768) {your code goes here}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use media queries with jQuery, but if you want to run your function just for a specific resolution you can use this code:

```
if(jQuery(window).width() > 768) {
   your code
}
```